# Penetration Testing Methodologies

Tags: penetration-test, black-hat, white-hat, grey-hat

I have some issues regarding the concept of **black, grey and white hat**.

Where and in what penetration testing methodology I can find the **black, grey or white hat** concept definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Penetration testing methodologies](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118796/penetration-testing-methodologies)

Comment: @tungsten your recommended answer is related to methodologies but it dose not respond to my question. I asked about definition on black, grey or white hat within methodologies rather then differences between methodologies as pointed out by your "duplicate".

Comment: I think the real answer is that the different "hats" are not described in a methodology at all. And that makes the proposed duplicate not helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## When referring to black, grey and white *hat* the following is the definition:

***White*** - A hacker who is hacking for profit with permission in order to test a system (This is called a penetration tester).

***Grey*** - A hacker who works as a penetration tester but also as a illegal hacker.

***Black*** - A hacker hacking illegally for any reason which can include all kinds of motives such as political, profit, revenge and so on...

## When referring to black, grey and white *box* testing the definition is the following:

***White*** - A tester has a deep understanding of the source code and the system and tries to build tailored tests to test the system

***Grey*** - Almost same as white except the tester has less knowledge of the system and mixes black and white testing together.

***Black*** - A tester will test the application as if he has no knowledge of application using all the normal testing techniques without diving into it deeper.

**Notice:** When speaking about "*some_color box penetration testing*" it is not common to do a grey box testing.